# preview CSS before submitting it as a final style

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, python-3.x, flask

I am trying to make an interface in which a user can edit their "user styles" css sheet and preview it. If they like what they see, they can commit it.

Here is what I do so far, as a very basic preliminary sketch:

```
class EditStylesForm(Form):
    """ a form to edit CSS styles """
    css = TextAreaField()
    submit = SubmitField('Commit Changes')
```

and in the views:

```
@admin.route('/styles', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def styles():
    """ render a form in which they can render stylesheets """
    try:
        with admin.open_resource('static/scss/user_styles.css') as f:
            form = EditStylesForm(css=f.read())
    except IOError:
        form = EditStylesForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        with open(os.path.join(current_app.root_path, 'static/scss/user_styles.css'), mode="w") as f:
            f.write(form.css.data)
    return render_template('admin/styles.html', form=form)
```

(yes, I am aware this is unsafe and can be improved). This will write a file with the css files shown in the textarea.

However, what I'd ideally like is a way to preview the css before submitting it and it being added to the websites style sheets. I imagine something like this is best handled on the front end.

Would there be a way to make a "preview" view for styles?

Answer (score 1):

QtWebKit (part of Qt, which has Python bindings available - search for PySide or PyQt) has a very full-featured Web display engine that supports style sheets.  You can display a web page within a python application and change its style sheet dynamically in response to user input.

Comment: can this be integrated into the web app itself, or are you suggesting making a separate GUI?